# Strategy Recommendation

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d

Problem: I need to detect the size/shape of watertight shapes described in an STL file.

I have explored a number of different approaches to this problem and I'm trying to decide between the following two directions using XNA.

Collision/proximity detection vs. ray-casting.

In both cases, I need a 3D Cube of boolean values indicating if the vertex at that point in space collides (or is proximate) to the surface of the mesh imported.

It seems like both collision detection or ray-casting would accomplish my goal, and I'm leaning towards Collision/proximity detection.  Before dumping hundreds of hours into investigating this process, are there any technological reasons that would prevent me from using it to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance - I look forward to any suggestions/help that can be provided.

Comment: Stack Overflow is best suited for direct questions that aren't based around opinion. EDIT: The comment I was responding to was deleted, as this one will be shortly.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thank you very much.  That is a clear delineator and makes perfect sense.  So..... is there a way to ask this question without just requesting an opinion?  I have edited the original question to make it less "opiniony" - and instead ask the more direct question of whether it would be possible to apply collision detection to this problem.  Is that any different or am I just trying to put lipstick on a pig? ;)

Comment: That does make it better, as it's now possible to answer, if someone does know of reasons against it. It's still extremely broad, though, which typically keeps questions from getting good answers. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/about has the actual rules about asking questions. It's still lacking in a few points mentioned there. One thing about your current question: it's only answerable if someone knows of a problem. No one's going to prove it's feasible, so you'll only actually get an answer if someone knows a problem.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.  And I understand that my making it specific, I am now limiting my answers (which IS okay) to specific reasons that this approach would NOT work.  I have read the about page and will do my best to keep my questions on target according to those rules.  Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you're talking about voxelizing a solid. The approach being followed in [this blog entry](http://www.nickdarnell.com/2011/09/robust-inside-and-outside-solid-voxelization/) is warning about a ray casting approach:

> The problem with the solid voxelization technique I was using
>   previously was that it used ray casting; making it impossible to
>   perform solid voxelization unless the mesh is watertight in addition
>   to having no anomalies like intersecting geometry.

If your solids don't fall outside this criteria, the ray casting approach seems to be perfectly valid, however the blog I referred to is making use of an advanced octree technique that seems to work regardless the shape of the solid.  It seems from the blog entry that some source code might even be available for you to inspect.   Anyways, I would inspect the academic paper (and source code if available) being referred to in the blog entry and decide, from a complexity standpoint, which approach is worth investing time.

Comment: A) Yes - that is precisely what I'm trying to do and B) that looks like a FANTASTIC resource to solve the problem.  Thank you VERY much.  I have only skimmed the link so far - but this looks RIGHT ON TRACK.  Thank you!

Comment: @eejai42: your're very welcome!  Glad the link proved to be helpful  =)

Comment: VERY helpful.  As it turns out (unfortunately), the I don't know if the specific solution provided will work for me - but... it has GREATLY increased my understanding of what "game engines" are actually doing.  It seems that they have a VERY "camera-centric" view of the world.  In other words, they handle, perspective, and clipping, etc.  This question (and answer really) have clearly demonstrated the problems associated with the RENDERING side of these engines.  Collision algorithms (like bullet tracking) may still work - but the RENDERING side is problematic!  Thanks again.